# How do I get a url parameter as nitial data into django's form wizard?

Tags: django, django-formwizard

I have in my urls.py the following line:

```
url(r'^voter/(?P<voter_id>{id})/$'.format(id = UUID_PATTERN), views.VoterWizard.as_view(views.FORMS), name='voter_index'),
```

In here I have a voter_id

Then in my views.py I have this class:

```
class VoterWizard(SessionWizardView):
    #initial_dict = {}   

    def get_form_initial(self, step): 
        initial = {} 
        print(self, step)
        return self.initial_dict.get(step, initial)

    def get_template_names(self):
        return [TEMPLATES[self.steps.current]]

    def done(self, form_list, **kwargs):
        # do_something_with_the_form_data(form_list)
        return HttpResponseRedirect('voting_success.html')
```

In general it works but I have no clue how I can populate some initial data to the form?

How can I read my **voter_id** from the url, perform a query and pass the result to the form?
I know I need to polulate the **initial_dict** or **initial** in the **get_form_initial**.

But how???

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I finally found the solution to add the following function:

```
    def get_context_data(self, form, **kwargs):
        context = super(VotingWizard, self).get_context_data(form, **kwargs)
        context.update({'voting': Voting.objects.get(uuid=self.kwargs['voting_id'])})
        return context
```